# c++ get tokens from a string with \t \n and empty space

Tags: c++, string, tabs, token

suppose I have a string

```
string text = "There are       many empty   space   and  tabs inside      ";
```

The empty space in this string might be \t or " ", and uncertain how many spaces or tabs between two tokens. How can I get tokens from that string? Which is a better method, 'strtok' or 'substring'?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/a/237280/2296458

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream in (text);
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

for (std::string temp; in >> temp; )
    tokens.push_back(temp);
```